# Equations in sentences?

Tags: mathematics

Some simple mathematic equations are converted into these sentences. What are they?

> 1. Candice's land (in $m^2$) is equal to the total area of Albert's land and Betty's land (in $m^2$).
> 2. On March 14$^{th}$, the frequency of the radiation waves is exponentially higher.
> 3. The price of a litre of water and cement squared is equal to ice, brick and two watery cement(s).
> 4. A number of power of a smaller number is derived from a power of number.
> 5. Signs over a reason is always temporary.

Comment: I'm pretty certain "ice" has to be water to the third power though.

Comment: Lol funny comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Complete answer changed again:

Candice's land (in $m^2$) is equal to the total area of Albert's land and Betty's land (in $m^2$).

> 1) $c^2=a^2+b^2$ Pythagoras' theorem.

On March 14th, the frequency of the radiation waves is exponentially higher.

> 2) Volume of a cylinder $V=(πr^2)h$

The price of a litre of water and cement squared is equal to ice, brick and two watery cement(s).

> 3) $(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2+2ab$

A number of power of a smaller number is derived from a power of number.

> 4) if $y=kx^n$ then $dy/dx=nkx^{n-1}$

Signs over a reason is always temporary.

> 5) $\tan θ = \sin θ/\cos θ$

Comment: I have chanfed the answer, although I am not sure about the second one

Comment: Just changed it again

Comment: Well done, faster than I thought!

Answer (score 2):

> March 14 could be written 314 which might be $\pi$ , that plus exponential could relate to Euler's equation